# Batch: for loop not working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Code is this:

```
@echo off
set str=abcd
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do set str=%str%%str%
echo %str%
```

At the end, I want str to be a long string. But its value is only abcdabcd. What is wrong? Why is this happening?

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: `for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do call set str=%%str%%%%str%%` should do the trick, regardless of delayed expansion enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barış, please use the search bar before asking **duplicated questions**.

---

In the script, you will need `delayedexpansion`, to start it, use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=abcd
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do set str=!str!!str!
echo %str%
```

Notice `%str%` becomes `!str!`(! means to expand the variable at command run-time, not phasing time.)

Another way of doing this is mentioned by  @JosefZ

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do call set str=%%str%%%%str%%
```

This uses `call`'s special variable expansion trick.